# Cannot insert '</div> <div>' to a position in html page using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to insert `</div><div id = '2'>` to my html page
This is current code:

```
<body>
   <div id='1'>
      <p>abc1</p>
      <p>abc2</p>
   </div>
</body>
```

This is code I want to be after insert:

```
<body>
  <div id='1'>
     <p>abc1</p>
  </div>
  <div id='2'>
     <p>abc2</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

My javascript code is

```
var bodyTag = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]; 
var divTag = bodyTag.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
var pCount = divTag.getElementsByTagName("p").length;
var str = '</div><div id = "2">';
var insert_pos = 1;
for(var i = 0 ; i < pCount; i++)
{
  if(i != insert_pos)
   {
     s += '<p>'+ divTag .getElementsByTagName("p")[i].innerHTML + '</p>'; 
   }
   else
   {
     s += '<p>'+ divTag .getElementsByTagName("p")[i].innerHTML + '</p>';
     s += str;
   }
}
```

I used javascript to insert with method innerHTML but it inserts only `<div id = '2'>`, `</div>` is not inserted.

Please help me! Thank you very much!

Comment: better use jQuery as specified in the below answer

Answer (score 5):

Try this : You can make use of `.after()` and `.append()` as shown below

```
$(function(){
  //add div2 after div1
  $('#1').after('<div id="2"></div>');
  //append last p to div2
  $('#2').append($('#1 p:last'));  
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j8kkbcm7/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

```js
var bodyTag = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]; 
var divTag = bodyTag.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
var pCount = divTag.getElementsByTagName("p").length;
var str = '<div>';
var insert_pos = 1;
for(var i = 0 ; i < pCount; i++)
{
  if(i == insert_pos)
   {
     str += '<p>'+ divTag .getElementsByTagName("p")[i].innerHTML + '</p>'; 
   }
}
str+='</div>';
bodyTag.innerHTML+=str;
```

```html
<body>
   <div id='1'>
      <p>abc1</p>
      <p>abc2</p>
   </div>
</body>
```

I think this could fulfill.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var pEls = document.getElementsByTagName('p'),
    parentDivEl = document.getElementById('1'),
    targetPEl = parentDivEl.removeChild(pEls[1]);

var divEl = document.createElement('div');
divEl.id = "2";
divEl.appendChild(targetPEl);

parentDivEl.parentNode.insertBefore(divEl, parentDivEl.nextSibling);
```

```html
<body>
   <div id='1'>
      <p>abc1</p>
      <p>abc2</p>
   </div>
</body>
```

Using Javascript, here you go...

```js
var pEls = document.getElementsByTagName('p'),
    parentDivEl = document.getElementById('1'),
    targetPEl = parentDivEl.removeChild(pEls[1]);

var divEl = document.createElement('div');
divEl.id = "2";
divEl.appendChild(targetPEl);

parentDivEl.parentNode.insertBefore(divEl, parentDivEl.nextSibling);
```

Comment: I thought about this solution. It's mean moving childs in a div to another. Because I had many <p> tag, so I want to find the way to insert to save time. Anyway, your solution is exact. Thank you very much, Sidrocks.

Answer (score 0):

This one is interesting.  I originally tried to use the insertAdjacentHTML function to insert the string '`</div><div id="2">`' after the first `<p>`, but strangely, the Dom rearranges these divs automatically to be '`<div id="2"></div>`'.

So, the next best option is to just do it manually.  I'm not sure if this will work in your case, but it does output the desired result with less javascript.

Check out this fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/justinbchristensen/k2y2uggj/

```
var div1 = document.getElementById('1');
var ps = div1.children;
div1.removeChild(ps[1]);
div1.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend','<div id="2"><p>abc2</p></div>');
```

1) Get the div by its ID, assign it to a variable 'div1'
2) Access the 2 child `<p>` of the div and assign them to 'ps'
3) Remove the second `<p>`
4) Insert the entire second `<div>` with its child `<p>`

Let me know if this will work for your situation. If not, I'm sure we can come up with something more creative.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much. I want to save the process time so I find the way to insert code like that. But it seems no way to insert. So, the right way to do is Moving the childs in this div to another. Thanks for your solution :)